# How to calculate total count of features in a dataset using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a Iris Dataset & I want to calculate total count of features in my dataset.Which library or function can be used to calculate the result???

Pls help me out.

Comment: What have you tried codewise? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I want a particular library or method which can be used to provide the total count of features in my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is the number of columns in the dataset, then this will be a simple way to do so:
len(iris.columns)

Comment: Thanks.Can u also tell how one can display the datatype of Features such as integer, float,boolean???